# Drag and Drop Items in desired position Listview WinRT

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am able to implement drag and drop from one ListView to the other ListView with the help from this blogpost

> [Windows 8 Drag Drop](http://www.renauddumont.be/post/2012/10/01/Windows-8-C-XAML-Drag-Drop-(English))

I am also able to reoder items in the same ListView

```
CanReorderItems="True"
```

But I am not able to drop an item from one ListView control to the other ListView control in the desired location.

Is there any way to find out the position where the drop occurred so that I can insert at that location using Insert method.

Comment: See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/536519/Extending-GridView-with-Drag-and-Drop-for-Grouping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/536519/Extending-GridView-with-Drag-and-Drop-for-Grouping

> The GridViewEx control implements drag and drop for cases which are
>   not supported by the regular GridView control:
>
> - For items panels other than WrapGrid, StackPanel, and    VirtualizingStackPanel.
> - When grouping is enabled.
>
> It also allows adding new groups to the underlying data source if the
>   user drags some item to the left-most or right-most edges of the
>   control.

Thank you @Xyroid!! This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

XAML ListView and GridView reorder and drag and drop sample (Windows 8.1)
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-ListView-and-GridView-6bd77f71